# Paper folding animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation

I am working on a kids application where the user should be able to fold a paper image like a physical paper and be able to cut it to which ever shape he likes.How to get paper folding animation for iPhone/iPad?Can any one please suggest me a way to achieve this task.
You will get an idea about my app from [this](http://www.mbtheme.com/ipad_apps/education/Paper-Cutting-for-Kids_72860-72860.html)

Comment: To get true folding animation I'm pretty sure you will need to use OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:urImage 
        duration:1.5 
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
        animations^{
            urImage.frame = requiredFrame;
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            //[urImage removeFromSuperview];
            // do something after animation has completed
        }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer This code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```